# Why does CMake skips the -I Flag from the g++ command line

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, compiler-flags

I have a working C project and just added some CPP stuff.

For includes I use `include_directories("./src/")` but the resulting commandline that is called from the generated makefile only contains `"./src/"` instead of the expected `-I"./src/"`

Whats going wrong with cmake here? Do I miss any difference between the C and the CPP compiler? Whe I add the -I to the commandline it just compiles as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who finds the same Symptoms, it has nothing to do with it just missed the `CXX` in my project:

Changed

```
project(my-project C ASM)
```

to

```
project(my-project C CXX ASM)
```

Now it works... I hope it will save someone else the few hours I spend on this.